# Best way to post data client to server C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, client-server

I'm currently developing windows client using Windows Form Application collecting some data from Windows machine. I need to send this data to server. But I don't know what is the best way to do that. I'm currently trying to WCF Web Service to get data and return true or false. But i need to learn fastest way to send data to server. The client must be reliable and fast. What is my options or best way to do that. The server only sends back data as true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [RhinoServiceBus](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-service-bus). It is fast and fairly easy to implement.  If you don't like that then I would be using WCF as well.

Comment: I think _RhinoServiceBus_ needs _MSMQ_ and i can't install _MSMQ_ with _msi installer_. Do you know a proper way to do that or run _RhinoServiceBus_ run without _MSMQ_

Answer (score 2):

If I had such task, I would use WCF web service as well.

The only one difference I would make: type void and throw exception in case of error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a low level network transport protocol based on Sockets like TCP or UDP, but then you have to manage conversion and serialization yourself.

In C# you would use TcpClient and TcpListener classes, and serialize your objects with some kind of serializer (BinaryFormatter in this example)

ServerCode:

```
...
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(8080);
listener.Start();
using  (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    //Assuming the client is sending an integer
    int arg = (int)formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream());
    ... //Do something with arg
    formatter.Serialize(result); //result is your boolean answer
} 
...
```

ClientCode:

```
 ...
   using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipaddress, 8080) //ipaddress is the ip address of the server
  {
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(client.GetStream(), 12) //12 is an example for the integer
   bool result = formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream());
   ... //do something with result
  }
   ...
```

But as you can see, the fastest(UDP may be faster, but does not guarantee sending the data) way is not the easiest (and not always the best).

So for an windows forms project I would use some kind of "ready-made" RMI/RPC API like WCF or ASP.Net web services

Comment: I must know data is sent and particlar job is done. I don't want any data loose.

Comment: UDP does not guarantee delivery. TCP adds that functionality.